# how to use array list to access methods of access list type object in java

Tags: java

in my program there are three class Student,School and TestStudent. I have declared students state inside student class and also there are methods for getting students subject,i have created an array list of type student in School class,but when i try to access student's method in school i get error newStudent type can not be resolved.Here are my codes.

```
public class Student {
        String name;
    String subject;
    int age;
    Student(String name,String subject,int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.age = age;
}
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
public String getSubject(){
    return this.subject;
}
public int getAge(){
    return this.age;
}

}

public class School {
public ArrayList <Student> students = new ArrayList <Student>(); 
public void addStudent(String name,String subject,int age){
    Student newStudent = new Student(name,subject,age);
    students.add(newStudent);
}
public void showSubject(String student){
     newStudent.getSubject();


}

}
```

Comment: changed the code using rohit's suggestion.now its working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newStudent.getSubject();
```

This is not what you want. Because you haven't retrieved that `student` yet from the `ArrayList`.

You would need to iterate over the `ArrayList`, and see which student have the name as passed in parameter.
So, just use a `for-each` loop to iterate over your `ArrayList`, and return appropriate Student.

So, your method should look like: -

```
public void showSubject(String student){
     for (Student student: students) {
        if (student.getName().equals(student)) {
            System.out.println(student.getSubject());
        }
     }
}
```

**Note that**, using a `Map` here would be a better idea as explained by @Peter in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14181222/1679863).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look up a student by name, I would make the name of a student immutable and use a `Map<String, Student>` instead.  This would allow you to write

```
 Student student = map.get(studentName);
```

Using a List, you would have to search through every entry as Rohit suggests.  Note: it is possible to have multiple students with the same name (as in real life) with a List.

Comment: Umm. Why have you explicitly specified making name of the student `immutable`? Since it's a `String`, it is implicit.

Comment: The `Student name;` should be final so it can be safely used as a key.

Answer (score 1):

`newStudent` is a local variable in `addStudent()`, hence you cannot access it from `showSubject()`.

I don't know what should be your logic of accessing the subject, but, for example, it could be accessed via `students.get(0).getSubject()` [provided the list is not empty]